# How to turn an array of nest children into a redirect/breadcrumb?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change a tree like structure into some redirects (breadcrumb fashion). I think the problem is that I am only building the first part of the redirects and not backfilling correctly somehow. I keep getting the first part of the redirects right, but once I have to reset the url is when I fail:

### Unwanted outcome

```js
[ '/wedding.html /wedding',
  '/wedding/monogram-series.html /monogram-series',
  '/wedding/monogram-series/test-theme.html /test-theme',
  '/test-theme-5.html /test-theme-5',
  '/classic-series.html /classic-series',
  '/stained-series.html /stained-series',
  '/fun-comical-series.html /fun-comical-series',
  '/fun-comical-series/test-theme-2.html /test-theme-2',
  '/test-theme-3.html /test-theme-3',
  '/test-theme-3/test-theme-4.html /test-theme-4',
  '/signature-series.html /signature-series',
  '/silhouette-series.html /silhouette-series',
  '/state-series.html /state-series' ]
```

I am generating the list into an array of strings. Here is the function I am currently using:

### Function being used (Yes I know this is not working correctly)

```js
const createUrls = (item) => {
  let urls = []
  let path = ``
  let prevEl = null

  const nest = (el) => {
    if (prevEl && (prevEl.id !== el.parentId)) {
      path = ``
    }
    prevEl = el
    path += `/${cleanUrl(el.name)}`
    urls.push(`${path}.html /${cleanUrl(el.name)}`)

    if (el.children && el.children.length) {
      el.children.forEach((childEl) => {
        nest(childEl)
      })
    }
  }

  nest(item)

  return urls
}
```

Essentially I need this

### Data being passed

```
{
  "id": 219,
  "name": "Wedding",
  "parentId": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 315,
      "name": "Monogram Series",
      "parentId": 219,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3309,
          "name": "Test-Theme",
          "parentId": 315
        },
        {
          "id": 3313,
          "name": "test-theme-5",
          "parentId": 315
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 316,
      "name": "Classic Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 317,
      "name": "Stained Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 318,
      "name": "Fun Comical Series",
      "parentId": 219,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3310,
          "name": "test-theme-2",
          "parentId": 318
        },
        {
          "id": 3311,
          "name": "test-theme-3",
          "parentId": 318,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 3312,
              "name": "test-theme-4",
              "parentId": 3311
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 319,
      "name": "Signature Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 320,
      "name": "Silhouette Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 324,
      "name": "State Series",
      "parentId": 219
    }
  ]
}
```

To turn into something like:

### Wanted outcome

```
[
  '/wedding.html /wedding', 
  '/wedding/monogram-series.html /monogram-series', 
  '/wedding/monogram-series/test-theme.html /test-theme',
  '/wedding/classic-series.html /classic-series',
  '/wedding/stained-series.html /stained-series',
  '/wedding/fun-comical-series.html /fun-comical-series',
  '/wedding/fun-comical-series/test-theme-2 /test-theme-2',
  '/wedding/fun-comical-series/test-theme-3 /test-theme-3',
  '/wedding/fun-comical-series/test-theme-3/test-theme-4 /test-theme-4',
  '/wedding/signature-series.html /signature-series',
  '/wedding/silhouette-series.html /silhouette-series',
  '/wedding/state-series.html /state-series'
]
```

---

### EDIT

Was asked to add the `cleanUrl` function to the code:

### cleanUrl function

```js
const cleanUrl = value => {
  if (value === null) value = ''
  let result = value
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gim, ' ')
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\./g, '')
    .toLowerCase()
  while (result.indexOf('--') > -1) {
    result = result.replace('--', '-')
  }
  if (result.slice(-1) == '-') {
    result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1)
  }
  if (result.slice(0, 1) == '-') {
    result = result.substring(1)
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: What is `cleanUrl` (like in `cleanUrl(el.name)`)?

Comment: turns names like `Monogram Series` into a cleanUrl text: `monogram-series`

Comment: Yes, but please add it to the code.

Comment: Added to the code!

Comment: isn't the URL the breadcrumb? In other words acme.com/fruits/apples/macintosh.  ...just saying - you might reconsider breadcrumbs alltogether. just my 2 cents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var stack = [];
var output = [];
var inputData = 
{
  "id": 219,
  "name": "Wedding",
  "parentId": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 315,
      "name": "Monogram Series",
      "parentId": 219,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3309,
          "name": "Test-Theme",
          "parentId": 315
        },
        {
          "id": 3313,
          "name": "test-theme-5",
          "parentId": 315
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 316,
      "name": "Classic Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 317,
      "name": "Stained Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 318,
      "name": "Fun Comical Series",
      "parentId": 219,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3310,
          "name": "test-theme-2",
          "parentId": 318
        },
        {
          "id": 3311,
          "name": "test-theme-3",
          "parentId": 318,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 3312,
              "name": "test-theme-4",
              "parentId": 3311
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 319,
      "name": "Signature Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 320,
      "name": "Silhouette Series",
      "parentId": 219
    },
    {
      "id": 324,
      "name": "State Series",
      "parentId": 219
    }
  ]
};

deepDive(inputData);
console.log(output);

function deepDive(node)
{
  var cleanName = cleanUrl(node.name);
  var i;

  stack.push(cleanName);
  output.push('/' + stack.join('/') + '.html /' + cleanName);
  if(node.children && node.children.length)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) deepDive(node.children[i]);
  }
  stack.pop();
}

function cleanUrl(name)
{
  return name.replace(' ','-').toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function nestParse(obj, prefix = '', data = []) {
  const cprefix = `${prefix}/${cleanUrl(obj.name)}`;
  data.push(`${cprefix}.html /${cleanUrl(obj.name)}`);
  (obj.children || []).forEach(c => nestParse(c, cprefix, data));
  return data;
};
console.log(nestParse(data));
```